# extract all text with entered delimeter in php

Tags: php, regex, string

**i have a text template like this:**

```
<p>fullname = #fullname#</p>
<p>company = #company#</p>
<p>phone = #phone#</p>
<p>phone = #phone4#</p>
<p>phone = #phone5#</p>
<p>phone = #phone6#</p>
<p>phone = #phone7#</p>
<p>phone = #phone8#</p>
```

**here i want to extract all this text which delimitered by # like this => fullname, company, phone, ...

what is the best way to do this regex or anything?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Make use of [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
<?php
$str= '<p>fullname = #fullname#</p>
<p>company = #company#</p>
<p>phone = #phone#</p>
<p>phone = #phone4#</p>
<p>phone = #phone5#</p>
<p>phone = #phone6#</p>
<p>phone = #phone7#</p>
<p>phone = #phone8#</p>';
preg_match_all('/#(.*?)#/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => fullname
    [1] => company
    [2] => phone
    [3] => phone4
    [4] => phone5
    [5] => phone6
    [6] => phone7
    [7] => phone8
)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/100852)

Comment: It is better to use the following, more efficient, alternative: `preg_match_all('/#([^#]*)#/', $str, $matches);`